# How to fix and get value from this jquery to asp net submit form?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, authentication

My form already submitted and connected , but the modal popup for jQuery are not appearing when user enter wrong password . It should have modal box to show user they entering wrong username/password.

i tried to validate data from jquery like i used in php . i tried it in the asp net mvc environment but i couldnt make the modal box appearing an no error showing .

```
    function validateForm() {

        var username = $("#username").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();

        var boolUsername = false;
        var boolPassword = false;

        if (username != "") {
            $("#usernameDiv").removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
            $('#usernameSpan').hide();
            boolUsername = true;
        }
        if (password != "") {
            $("#passwordDiv").removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
            $('#passwordSpan').hide();
            boolPassword = true;
        }

        //Validation
        if (username == "") {
            $("#usernameDiv").addClass('has-error');
            $('#usernameSpan').html("Enter username");
            $('#usernameSpan').show();
        }
        if (password == "") {
            $("#passwordDiv").addClass('has-error');
            $('#passwordSpan').html("Enter password");
            $('#passwordSpan').show();
        }
        if (boolUsername && boolPassword) {
            $('#loading').css('visibility', 'visible');
            $.post("#form1",
                {
                    username: username,
                    password: password
                },
                function (data, status) {
                    if (data == "1") {
                        $('#loading').css('visibility', 'hidden');
                        resetForm();
                        window.location.replace("mainPanel.php");
                    }
                    else if (data == "3") {
                        $('#loading').css('visibility', 'hidden');
                        resetForm();
                        window.location.replace("mainPanel.php");
                    }
                    else if (data == "2") {
                        $('#loading').css('visibility', 'hidden');
                        resetForm();
                        window.location.replace("mainPanel.php");
                    }
                    else if (data == "4") {
                        $('#loading').css('visibility', 'hidden');
                        $("#alertBox").addClass('modal-danger');
                        $('#alertTitle').html("Fail");
                        $('#alertText').html("Access Denied!");
                        $('#alertBox').modal('show');
                    }
                    else if (data == "0") {
                        $('#loading').css('visibility', 'hidden');
                        $("#alertBox").addClass('modal-danger');
                        $('#alertTitle').html("Fail");
                        $('#alertText').html("Sorry, the username and password does not match.");
                        $('#alertBox').modal('show');
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#loading').css('visibility', 'hidden');
                        $("#alertBox").addClass('modal-danger');
                        $('#alertTitle').html("Fail");
                        $('#alertText').html(data);
                        $('#alertBox').modal('show');
                    }

                });
        }
    }

    function resetForm() {
        $('#usernameSpan').hide();
        $('#passwordSpan').hide();
    }
```

**and this is my controller**

```
    {
        attendanceselangorEntities db = new attendanceselangorEntities();
        var dataItem = db.tblusers.Where(x => x.userNm == model.userNm && x.userPw == model.userPw).FirstOrDefault();

        if (dataItem != null)
        {

            var q = (from tu in db.tblusers
                     join tp in db.tblpersonnels on tu.userId equals tp.perId
                     join rt in db.refusertypes on tu.userTyId equals rt.userTyId
                     join rp in db.refpositions on tu.compId equals rp.posId
                     select new { tu.userNm, tu.userId, tp.perId, rt.userTyId, rp.posId });

            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(dataItem.userNm, false);
            string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

            Session["Id"] = db.tblusers.Where(x => x.userNm == model.userNm).SingleOrDefault().userId;
            Session["Username"] = db.tblusers.Where(x => x.userNm == model.userNm).SingleOrDefault().userNm;
            Session["Role"] = db.tblusers.Where(x => x.userNm == model.userNm).FirstOrDefault().userTyId;

            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                     && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("mainPanel", "Home", new { id = dataItem.userId });
            }
        }
        else
        {

            return View();
        }

    }
```

**my modal**

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="alertBox">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="alertTitle"></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p id="alertText"></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

i expected  that the modal box will appear for any invalid messages . i was expected that the page will not refreshed when the submit button is clicked.

and this is my error on console page

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).icheck is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):171)
    at j (VM225 jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (VM225 jquery.min.js:2)
(anonymous) @ (index):171
j @ jquery.min.js:2
k @ jquery.min.js:2
setTimeout (async)
r.readyException @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:2
j @ jquery.min.js:2
k @ jquery.min.js:2
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:2
i @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
fire @ jquery.min.js:2
i @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
k @ jquery.min.js:2
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:2
i @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
fire @ jquery.min.js:2
i @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
ready @ jquery.min.js:2
S @ jquery.min.js:3
```

Answer (score 0):

try to call modal popup from the jquery as below:

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

Comment: $('#alertBox').modal('show'); . alertbox is the id for my modal sir.

Comment: is still the same sir . the modal box still not appearing .

Comment: check the console in developers tools of the browser. may be some error is occurrings.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) . There are several error like this sir ? how do i want to fix this ?